# Filter 500 files with awk, then cat results to single file

Tags: bash, awk, cat

I'm in a directory with a couple thousand files, but the files I want to filter all have the following syntax: `*.imputed.*_info`

I want to use awk to filter out the records in each file where the 5th column of data has a value > 0.50 and I was able to do that with: `awk '{if($5 >= .5) {print}}' filename`.

That too worked.  I then tried to loop through all 500 or so files and concatenate records from each that match this criteria.

I tried the following but I am not getting the syntax right.

```
touch snplist.txt
for name in *.imputed.*_info; do
    snps="awk '{if($5 >= .5) {print}}' $name"
    cat snplist.txt "$snps" > snplist.txt
done
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code overwrites the output file in each iteration.  You also do not actually call `awk`.

What you want to do is something like

```sh
awk '$5 >= 0.5' ./*.imputed.*_info >snplist.txt
```

This would call `awk` with all your files at once, and it would go through them one by one, in the order that the shell expands the globbing pattern.  If the 5th column of any line in a file is greater or equal to 0.5, that line would be outputted (into `snplist.txt`). This works since the default action, if no action (`{...}` block) is associated with a condition, is to output the current line.

In cases where you have a *large* number of files (many thousands), this may generate an "Argument list too long" error.  In that case, you may want to loop:

```sh
for filename in ./*.imputed.*_info; do
    awk '$5 >= 0.5' "$filename"
done >snplist.txt
```

Note that the result of `awk` does not need to be stored in a variable.  Here, it's just outputted and *the loop* (and therefore all commands inside the loop) is redirected into `snplist.txt`.

For many thousands of files, this would be quite slow since `awk` would need to be invoked for each of them individually.

To speed things up, in the cases where you have too many files for a single invocation of `awk`, you may consider using `xargs` like so:

```sh
printf '%s\0' ./*.imputed.*_info | xargs -0 awk '$5 >= 0.5' >snplist.txt
```

This would create a list of filenames with `printf` and pass them off to `xargs` as a nul-terminated list.  The `xargs` utility would take these and start `awk` with *as many of them as possible* at once, in batches.  The output of the whole pipeline would be redirected to `snplist.txt`.

This `xargs` alternative is assuming that you are using a Unix, like Linux, which has an `xargs` command that implements the non-standard `-0` option to read nul-terminated input. It also assumes that you are using a shell, like `bash`, that has a *built-in* `printf` utility (`ksh`, the default shell on OpenBSD, would not work here as it has no such built-in utility).

---

For the `zsh` shell (i.e. not `bash`):

```
autoload -U zargs
zargs -- ./*.imputed.*_info -- awk '$5 >= 0.5' >snplist.txt
```

This uses `zargs`, which is basically a reimplementation of `xargs` as a loadable `zsh` shell function.  See `zargs --help` (after loading the function) and the `zshcontrib(1)` manual for further information about that.

Comment: If the arg list is too long for awk, surely it is too long for printf too.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant:  No.  ```awk``` is a program.  `printf` is a shell builtin, and is therefore exempt from the "Argument list too long" error.

Comment: @Scott Correct, except when `printf` is not available as a shell built-in, as with OpenBSD's `ksh` shell, as I mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

Just do this :

```
awk '$5 >= .5' *.imputed.*_info > snplist.txt
```

Comment: You can move the `if (condition)` into `awk`'s _condition_ part, and then the `{print}` can be omitted as it's the default action if none is specified. `awk '$5 >= .5' *.imputed.*_info`. But then you're repeating [Kusalananda's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/556430/100397)..

Answer (score 3):

I have a habit of using `find` for this kind of thing.

```
find . -type f -name "*.imputed.*_info" -exec awk '$5 >= 0.5' {} \; > ./snplist.txt
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that the `{} +` is equivalent to `xargs`, vs. `{} \;` being slow like a shell `for` loop that runs awk separately on each file.